# Guillemets in LaTeX («»)

Tags: symbols, punctuation, csquotes

I need the characters «» in my LaTeX document.  I'm writing in English though, and I don't want to use Babel.  I have the following hack but I'd like a better way:

```
\newcommand{\q}[1]{{%
\font\larm = larm1000%
\larm%
\char 190}{#1}{%
\font\larm = larm1000%
\larm%
\char 191}}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

- With [standard methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol), you will find `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright`. For this you need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (which is recommended anyways).
- Using the language switching capabilities of [`babel`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=babel), e.g. `\foreignlanguage`.
- Using [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) and its `\foreignquote` command.

Personally, I would recommend the third option.

The similar looking mathmode symbols ≪ and ≫ (much less/greater than) are created with `\ll` and `\gg`.

Comment: I'd probably favour `csquotes`, as it means you keep the semantics of the mark-up and can reuse the source in other places more readily.

Comment: Unfortunately it is indeed spelled incorrectly. It should be guillemetleft and guillemetright (with an "e"). A guillemot with an "o" is a seabird :-) But I think we're stuck with it.

Comment: @PeterFlynn In my case it works only with ''o''.

Comment: Of course. Read what I said. It was misspelled when created.

Comment: See my last answer, `\MarkOuterQuote{"}` is simpler with `csquote` package

Comment: And if you are using it regularly here in a function: `\newcommand{\guillemet}[1]{\guillemotleft #1 \guillemotright}`

Comment: Although the thread is for ways in which to *prevent* using `babel`, I also needed `fontenc` to make the guillemets look right *with* `babel`. Without it, they look flattened and with strokes that resemble Arial.

Answer (score 32):

There's also a convenient way to do it with Latin Modern:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

<<Quoted text>>.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and intuitive!

Comment: Tried inside a `knitr` document. and this was the only way that really worked for me. I must admit I am surprised cause the other answers looked sound, too. However thanks Andrey!

Comment: Does not work for me. I use koma-script book with babel

Answer (score 17):

You could type it directly if you use an utf8 encoding :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
«For example.»
\end{document}
```

But, the automatic spacing isn't correct — at least for French typography. As suggested in the comments, you can always input manually the correct spacing (~, for non-breaking space).

Comment: I think you can add the due non-breaking spaces manually with the `~` character.

Answer (score 13):

I find this way is very convenient:

package:    `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}`

in text:    `\og text \fg{}`

Comment: This is indeed the correct way when using French with `babel`.

Comment: @egreg and wrong for non-French text.

Answer (score 4):

The best I now use in french is:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

I now can use `"` to as "guillemet" and it's correctly replaced by `«` and `»`

Comment: This did not work in French for me.

Comment: Weird, it works perfectly for me (I'm french)

Comment: Have you tried with Babel, cause it definitely worked here

Answer (score 2):

I tried several of those options all leading to a small square instead of «». This did the trick for me.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[francais]{babel} % guillemets \og text \fg{}
\usepackage{aeguill} % guillemets
 \begin{document}
 \og text \fg{}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: The OP requests this without use of Babel. Also, Babel has various unwanted side effects such as hyphenation, change of parindent in the first line, change of itemization bullets etc.