# Marks like "«»"

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guillemets in LaTeX («»)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/guillemets-in-latex)

I need to make some quote marks like this: "« »" in my Latex document.

```
      \begin{document}

       Some text with quote marks like "« »"

      \end{document}
```

How can I do?

Comment: The linked question, unlike this one, states that the OP doesn't want to use `babel`. If you need these quotation marks in order to comply with your language's typographical conventions (for example french), `babel` will still be the easiest solution.

Comment: Take a look at `csquotes`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use T1 encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

Some text with quote marks like ``<<'' and ``>>''

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also encode your input file as UTF-8, you can use direct input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

Some text with quote marks like ``«'' and ``»''

\end{document}
```