# « and » characters not correctly displayed

Tags: symbols, unicode

The usual way to type the « and » characters in LaTeX is to use the commands `"<`, for «, and `">`, for », while using the `babel` package with the italian option, and the `inputenc` package with the utf8 option.

This always worked for me, but since yesterday this combination doesn't work anymore. For instance, this is the way this MWE is rendered:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
"<Hello world!">
\end{document}
```

[image: «Hello world!»]

I realized this while working on a document on which I was using more or less ten different packages, so I initially thought that some packages maybe were conflicting with others, but then I tried to render a previous document on which the « and » characters were correctly displayed, without changing anything in the code, and they were now displayed this way too.

Do you have a clue about what's going on?

The TeX version I'm using is this one:

`TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)`

Comment: Besides @egreg's comment, you have to issue the command `\setactivedoublequote` after loading `babel`.  Try `texdoc babel-italian` and read the caption of table 1.

Comment: Besides what Arash says (correct), you also *need* `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and then you just have to type `<<Hello world>>` (no `\setactivedoublequote` needed for this).

Comment: Curious, `\setactivedoublequote`works. I never used it though :\

Comment: You could consider [switching to `csquotes`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39285/34551) to handle your quotes without bad surprises.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/guillemets-in-latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put `\setactivedoublequote` in the preamble. I'm not sure why I never had to use it, but whatever, now it works.